# Android search dialog to be visible always

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, search-dialog

Is it possible to pin the search dialog to be pinned always at the top of the application activity?

The problem what I have is, if a user clicks some where else in the activity, say by mistake, the search dialog goes off, and the user has to click on the search phone button.

Since my sample app is a search app, I want it to be visible always at the top of my activity.

Is there a way, does android API allows this?

Thanks

Edit with Code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        onSearchRequested();

        Intent intent = getIntent();

        if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
              String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);

              Log.d("search", query);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
```

Activity:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

searchconfig

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
</searchable>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you control what else there is in your Activity, you can ensure that no other elements are clickable/focusable (except for your search field).

Anyway, we could be more helpful if you showed us the actual code you were having trouble with.

Comment: Infact, I want it to be visible in case of start of application as well as result activity (list activity). However softkey should come up only when the dialog is active, (clicked) Can you please let me know how to achieve this?

Comment: Or.. Is it possible to put this android default search dialog in a separate layout and gets displayed always, irrespective of what is being clicked in the activity?

If so could you please let me know how to do it, using the above layout what I have?

Thanks